# Как сделать pageUp/pageDown в ListView?

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте!
Столкнулся с тем, что не получается сделать прокрутку `ListView` на страницу либо вниз, либо вверх, как это реализовано в `Scrollview`:

```
    scrollView.pageScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
    scrollView.computeScroll();
```

Нужно как то по аналогии сделать прокрутку в `ListView`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

PS: суть вопроса в том, чтобы сделать 2 кнопки (по нажатию на первую 'listview' прокручивается на страницу вниз, по нажатию на вторую - вверх).

Comment: В итоге обошелся scrollview **:(**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ListView внутри ScrollView](http://habrahabr.ru/post/125107/)

Comment: нормально ли это будет? у меня обычный listveiw, без всяких заморочек. просто получится вложенность

Comment: Чесно говоря несовсем поятно с влпроса что ты хочешь.... ЛистВью и так список с прокруткой, где там цеплять скролВью и зачм непонятно

Comment: мне нужно сделать две кнопки, по нажатию первой, listview прокручивается на страницу вниз, а по нажатию второй прокручивается на страницу вверх, такая возможность есть в scrollview, но я не нашел как сделать это для listview

Comment: вероятней всего надо будет писать свой listview....